# Cleanly stopping a supervision subtree kills the VM if there is a supervised port; why?

Tags: erlang, elixir

I have an elixir application with a simple 1 for 1 supervisor whose children are 1 for 1 supervisors that have a number of workers. Like this:

```
------------------
|  SupSup (s141) |
------------------
        |
        |-------------------------------------- ...
        |                      |
------------------    ------------------
|    Sup (141)   |    |    Sup (141)   |        ...
------------------    ------------------
    |        |            |        |
----------            ----------
| Worker |  ...       | Worker |  ...           ...
----------            ----------
```

Some workers have Erlang ports (created with `Porcelain`) to external processes. The application needs to stop subtrees at the `Sup` level of the tree. The code to do this (running in the `Worker`) is `spawn(fn() -> Supervisor.terminate_child(Sup, pid) end)` where `pid` is the Worker's Sup's pid (looked up via `:gproc`).

On Fedora 24, using `Supervisor.terminate_child()` causes the Erlang VM to crash:

```
erl_child_setup closed

Crash dump is being written to: erl_crash.dump...done
```

On Ubuntu 16.04, there is no crash and the subtree exits cleanly as expected.

Why?

This is a rather complex situation so pasting the whole application is inappropriate. I put everything needed to replicate the problem including the Fedora 24 crash dump in the [murder_supervisor_test project](https://github.com/sampscl/murder_supervisor_test) at GitHub.

Edit 1: On Fedora, the environment is OTP 19.2 / Elixir 1.4.1 built with kerl and kiex. On Ubuntu, Erlang and Elixir is 19.1 / 1.4.0-1 and were installed with apt-get from erlang-solutions.

Edit 2: Removing Erlang & Elixir on Ubuntu and reinstalling 19.2 / 1.4.1 with kerl and kiex did not change the result: no VM crash on Ubuntu.

Comment: If this is only happening on Fedora, I would say it is an issue with either Fedora's Erlang or Elixir package. Try compiling Erlang and Elixir from source on Fedora and see if you still have the same issue.

Comment: Are you running the same version of Erlang on both systems? Looks like a bug was fixed for a similar error in 19.1: http://erlang.org/pipermail/erlang-questions/2016-November/090774.html.

Comment: I updated the question with dev environment data

Comment: @Clay can you try running this with the same version on both the systems? 19.1 on Fedora and/or 19.2 on Ubuntu.

Comment: @Dogbert I re-edited the question -- 19.2 / 1.4.1 on Ubuntu still worked as expected

Comment: @Clay I'm confused by your description. If you're trying to terminate a supervisor, the call should be `Supervisor.terminate_child(SupSup, pid)` instead of `Supervisor.terminate_child(Sup, pid)`.